OnePulse wont output on specific PIN
I need the µC to output one single pulse (HIGH) for a duration of 1,925 ms (0,001925s) and then LOW on a single PIN for a current project. I'm using the system clock of 72 MHz, use a prescaler of 71 for it to be 1 MHz and the ARR to be 1924, so the duration should be right.
I configured Timer 1 to one pulse mode and used pin a8 as the output for Timer 1. The pulse should start as soon as I run the code.
I tried to check the pulse using an oscilloscope, but nothing happened when I ran the code. Did I make a mistake in the code, or am I using the osci wrong? This is my first time using the cube ide and I'm not really good at programming either.
I'll paste the main function and the timer, as well as the gpio function, below. A lot of the code is probably unnecessary but I didn't want to remove something I didn't know about.
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_PCD_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, LD6_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  while (1)
  {
  }
}


static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();

  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 71;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 1924;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim1, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim1, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  TIM_OnePulse_InitTypeDef sConfig;
  sConfig.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfig.Pulse = 1924;
  sConfig.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfig.ICPolarity = TIM_ICPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfig.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfig.ICFilter = 0;

  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfig, TIM_CHANNEL_1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, CS_I2C_SPI_Pin | LD4_Pin | LD3_Pin | LD5_Pin | LD7_Pin | LD9_Pin | LD10_Pin | LD8_Pin | LD6_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DRDY_Pin | MEMS_INT3_Pin | MEMS_INT4_Pin | MEMS_INT1_Pin | MEMS_INT2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS_I2C_SPI_Pin | LD4_Pin | LD3_Pin | LD5_Pin | LD7_Pin | LD9_Pin | LD10_Pin | LD8_Pin | LD6_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_TIM1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}



I believe setting sConfig.Pulse to the same value as htim1.Init.Period is wrong. The pulse width is the difference between the ARR value and the CRR1 value. Try setting the sConfig.Pulse lower and see what happens. And read the reference manual for your MCU.
